# SQL Server query for checking existing login and user if exist then exit else create

Tags: sql-server

I have written a query to check an existing login, user in a SQL Server database - if the user exists, then it exits, else it creates the user with same id.

Query below its just working as expected:

```
DECLARE @selectQuery AS varchar(50);
SET @selectQuery = 'select name from sys.sql_logins where name="AXA8080"';

IF @selectQuery IS NOT NULL
    DROP USER AXA8080;

IF @selectQuery IS NOT NULL
    DROP LOGIN AXA8080;

CREATE LOGIN AXA8080 WITH PASSWORD = 'mypass#1';

USE [DB_NAME];

CREATE USER [AXA8080] FOR LOGIN [AXA8080] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo];
ALTER ROLE [db_reader] ADD MEMBER [AXA8080];
```

`AXA8080` is the user .

Can someone tell me why I get this error:

> User does exist (Since I have not created the user yet it need to be done through this query)

Any help would be great !

Thanks,
Atul

Comment: I am dropping user then login if they exist else create login then user of the same ID i searched .Query in question

Comment: @selectQuery is just a string.  You're not running that query.

Comment: Also, double quotes is not correct for the string literal inside the query.

Comment: Thanks David ,Joel .It worked now

Answer (score 0):

Here it is!

Caution: if the user owns the database, schema, assembly you will get an error.

```
IF USER_ID('AXA8080') IS NOT NULL
DROP USER AXA8080;

IF SUSER_ID('AXA8080') IS NOT NULL
DROP LOGIN AXA8080;

CREATE LOGIN AXA8080 WITH PASSWORD = 'mypass#1';

USE [DB_NAME];

CREATE USER [AXA8080] FOR LOGIN [AXA8080] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo];
ALTER ROLE [db_reader] ADD MEMBER [AXA8080];
```